# Placing two graphs side by side when one of them has a discontinuity in the y-axis

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to create a two graph Figure with `pgfplots`. However, the result is not exactly what I want, because I expected the two graphs to appear side by side, but they are oddly aligned instead. In the `pgfplot` manual (p. 21) one can read

[image]
and, therefore, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

My code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
         ticks=none, 
         axis x line=bottom,
         axis y line=left,
         xmin=0,xmax=7,
         ymin=0,ymax=12]
      \addplot[
         domain = 0:7,
         samples =200,
         ] {x};
      \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
         ticks=none, 
         axis x line=bottom,
         axis y line=left,
         axis y discontinuity=crunch,
         xmin=0,xmax=1.3,
         ymin=0.5,ymax=1.3]
      \addplot[
         domain = 0:sqrt(1/3),
         samples =200,
         ] {sqrt(7/6-x^2)};
      \addplot[
         domain = sqrt(1/3):sqrt(7/6),
         fill = gray,
         fill opacity = 0.1,
         samples =200,
         y filter/.expression={x==sqrt(7/6 )?0:y},
         ] {sqrt(7/6-x^2)}\closedcycle;
      \addplot[
         domain = 0:7,
         samples =200,
         ] {sqrt(5/6)};
      \fill[gray, opacity = 0.1] (0,0) -- (0,0.9129) -- (0.5774,0.9129) -- (0.5774,0);
      \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

*Edit:* Is it, perhaps, a consequence of the `crunch` of the axis in the rightmost graph? I think it is: removing `axis y discontinuity=crunch` results in the two graphs being aligned.

[image]

Adding `\usepackage{showframe}` shows that the resulting Figure is wider than the margins even when the two diagrams are correctly aligned. However, the misalignement persists when the `crunch` is present even if the size of the individual plots is reduced to have them fit in the page width.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the MWE. Please create separate questions for each of the three sub-question (Thx: I see that you have done that already but this question still has the sub-questions).

Comment: Unrelated, the `tikz` package is not needed in the MWE, you can remove it.

Comment: Please also add `\usepackage{showframe}` to your code and you will see that your diagrams are too wide (not sure if that is the root cause of your problem). I added a screenshot to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Community Comment:** Normally, it is custom on this site to ask "one question per question" :).
- **Avtual Answer:** Below, you find a proposal for your first question (side-by-side), using `\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}`.
- **PGFPLOTS Manual Reference:** I also added a screenshot from the related section in the manual.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    % Shared options for all diagrams.
    group style = {
            group size = 2 by 1
        },
        height = 40mm,
        width = 30mm,
        ]
\nextgroupplot[
         ticks=none, 
         axis x line=bottom,
         axis y line=left,
         xmin = 0,
         xmax = 7,
         ymin = 0,
         ymax = 12,
         ]
\addplot[
         domain = 0:7,
         samples =200,
         ] {x};
\nextgroupplot[
         ticks = none, 
         axis x line = bottom,
         axis y line = left,
         axis y discontinuity = crunch,
         xmin = 0,
         xmax = 1.3,
         ymin = 0.5,
         ymax = 1.3,
         ]
\addplot[
         domain = 0:sqrt(1/3),
         samples = 200,
         ] {sqrt(7/6-x^2)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Remark:** `\usepackage{showframe}` shows that your diagrams are too wide.

[image]

Comment: I thought there was no need for ```groupplots``` for just two plots, because their being on the same paragraph was enough for them to appear side by side.

Comment: @Patricio I do not claim that this is the best solution but at least it is a well-documented solution and it took me 5 min without trial and error.